# Python multiprocessing get item index from loop

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Im trying to spread a loop over several processes and print each iteration's index as its processed. What am I missing as this is as far as I got.
Ive tried

```
 import multiprocessing
 import os

 def f(key_value):
     print (key_value)
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
     for _ in pool.imap(f, range(100)):
      pass
```

and also

```
   from multiprocessing import Pool 
   def th(ur):
      print (ur)
   if __name__ == '__main__':
     pool = Pool(2)
     results = pool.map(th,range(100))
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the speed of the main process against the worker.
The main process exits before the end of the processing. (when not using `.close` `.join`)

And also you **missed a return value** in the tasklet function.

The following code works as expected:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(tuple_value):
    index, value = tuple_value
    print("Index: {} Value: {}".format(index, value))
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    pool.imap(f, enumerate(range(100)))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Output in Python 3.x and 2.7:

```
$ python3 test.py 
Index: 0 Value: 0
Index: 1 Value: 1
Index: 2 Value: 2
Index: 3 Value: 3
[...]
```

Comment: Still stuck nothing comes back

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal sorry i don't get what the problem is... Is it there is no output?

Comment: Yes no output thats the issue. kindly also adjust the last line of your code. Thanks

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal oh ok i see. i got it. give me a couple of minutes to update the answer. :)

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal check it now

Comment: Still no output. Im using python 3.x let me try on a 2.7

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal in my terminal it works in py3 and py2 i've attached output

Comment: This is very strange, Ive done a copy and paste on 3.x and 2.7 on 2 different computers. What on earth should I be looking at right now ? Lol.

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal are you using an interactive terminal? try saving it to a file and launch it directly as in my test.... apart from this... i don't have more clues... :/

Comment: Lol, Im running from a file. There must be an issue somewhere. What would be the case if I import pool ?

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal let me know if you find out something. My test runs on  linux.

Comment: Okay , both of my tests Im running on Windows. I know the import multiprocessing works because I am able to get a CPU count.

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal ok we've found the problem.... windows... ;)  i'm not able to help you in windows sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

i tested your second example and it works (except for some indentation issues). Tested on windows 10 64bit with python 2.7.13

I also added some random wait time, to verify the async print.

```
import time
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool 

def th(ur):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,3))
    print (ur)
    #return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(2)
    results = pool.map(th,range(10))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that none of them are working on Windows

Comment: @tagnihuguespascal sorry, but with "and it works" i meant on windows... i tested with python 2.7.xx on windows 10 64bit